# How can we use the noun "canoe" as a verb here?

Tags: verbs, nouns

Here is the sentence:

> We will **canoe** down the river this summer.

Here *canoe* is a noun that is like a boat. How can we say "canoe down" in the sentence above?

Comment: "Canoe" here is a verb. You can canoe down the river, sail down the river, swim down the river, etc.

Comment: It is hard to know which "boat" words can be used as a verb and which cannot. "I kayaked down the river" and "I punted down the river" are good but "I rowboated down the river" and "I sailboated down the river" are not; you'd say "rowed" or "sailed".

Comment: @EricLippert That's a good point.  It's definitely a challenge.  But in this case, the OP could find the verb *canoe* [in a dictionary](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/canoe).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right. Canoe is a noun but then it's also a verb!

> [Canoe (v)](http://www.wordwebonline.com/en/CANOE) - (sport) travel by canoe.

Answer (score 1):

The word *canoe* can be either noun or verb.

> **[canoe](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/canoe)**
>   *noun*: a light, narrow boat with pointed ends and no keel, propelled with a paddle or paddles..
>   *verb*: travel in or paddle a canoe.

It's always a good idea to consult dictionaries.

Also, in English, [verbification is common](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/42666/what-is-it-called-when-a-non-verb-is-used-as-a-verb):

> [Verbification](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Verbification#Verbing), or verbing, is the creation of a verb from a noun, adjective or other word. Verbification is a type of functional shift. It is also a form of derivation, and may involve any of the various derivational processes.

And yes, in order to answer this question, with the help of Google's search engine, I googled both *canoe*'s definitions, and also *verbification*. One dictionary also lists [googleable](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/google?q=google) as a word too.

Comment: See also http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/42666/what-is-it-called-when-a-non-verb-is-used-as-a-verb

Comment: Some canoes also have a motor.